# How to ensure that the main branch will not be changed due to changes in the ignored files of the new branch?

Tags: git, github

Many files are generated during the running of the program and are very large.

I added these file paths to the `.gitignore` file. When I need to make some new changes, I create a new branch, make changes on the new branch, and then run the new branch to determine whether my changes are reasonable.

Let's suppose that I made a mistake and I wanted to restore it back. I ran `git reset` to restore it but I found that it still couldn't run because some files that I ignored in my settings changed. I want to switch back to the main branch, delete this new branch, and start again. But I found that the master branch can no longer run. How should I set them to not affect each other?

Comment: Nothing you can say to git can have _any_ effect on files you have told git to ignore. It is ignoring them. It has no record of their previous state. You have told git to leave those files entirely in your hands, and that is what it has done. Dealing with that is entirely up to you. You could empty the work tree and check out `master` or whatever, but then these "generated" files will be missing and dealing with _that_ will be entirely up to you.

Comment: I know that. But I want to know if there is any way I can ignore them when commit. But can they be independent of each other when switching branches?

Comment: No, they can not be independent of each other for the simple reason that unless you start adding separate worktrees for separate branches, you only have 1 copy of these files, and since you've asked git to ignore them, git ignores them. Whatever was left behind from your secondary branch in such files, when you switch back to the main branch, will still be there. You might want to look into the `git worktree` command, or get into the habit of deleting untracked files when you switch branches.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If a file is ignored and it is not already part of the index, git will not track it.

Let's say that you want to ignore `very_large_file.out` so you add it to your `.gitignore`. Since you are ignoring it, when you switch back and forth between `master` and your branch, that file is not updated. You mentioned that you run a `git reset`. That command has no effect on file `very_large_file.out` because it's being ignored.

In the comments you ask:

> can they be independent of each other when switching branches?

The answer is that since you are ignoring them, git will do nothing to them at all. **You** will have to do something for that to happen. Two ways of doing it come to my mind:

1. Create those very large files in subfolders, for example `output/master/` and `output/mybranch` and ignore these folders
2. Remove and recreate those files when you switch branches

These are just two ways of doing it that occur to me without knowing your application. I'm sure you can come with other solutions or ideas about how to manipulate those files since it's your application.

The important idea you have to keep in your mind is that since you are ignoring those files, git will not touch them. So whatever you need to do to them after switching branches, you have to perform the actions by yourself and not rely on git.

There is a thing in git called [`hooks`](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks) that can help you run scripts when certain events happen like after a commit, before a push, etc. Maybe one of those hooks can be of help to automate the manipulation of those files.

Also, you can have a look at `git-lfs` ([large file support](https://git-lfs.github.com/)) which would allow to track those files without making your repository grow out of control. However, before using `git-lfs` you should first ask yourself if those files need to be in the repository. Since you said that those very large files are the output of running the application, my first guess would be that you should probably ignore them.